# ExternalChange address book

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Help. I try to keep track of changes in address book. but the method

```
NSError err;
ABAddressBook iOSAddressBook = ABAddressBook.Create(out err);
iOSAddressBook.ExternalChange += (object sender, ExternalChangeEventArgs e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("qorkkkk");
    };
```

does not work.

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an exception?

Comment: no exceptions. I launch the application click home button. in address book something changing. back to the application and the console is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
/*First, Make change in viewDidLoad Method from where you want to change addressbook Record.*/
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);
    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, addressBookChanged, (__bridge void *)(self));
}
//Then,
    /*------- method will call when contact updated  ------*/
void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context)
{
    @try {
        [YourVewControllerObj updateRecord];
//        YourViewController *viewController = (__bridge YourViewController*)context;
//        [viewController updateRecord];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@",exception.description);
    }
}

    /*------- Method call if make any change in conatct ------*/
+(void)updateRecord
{
  NSMutableDictionary *dictPerson= [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook =ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error) ;
    ABRecordID record = ABRecordGetRecordID(ABRecordRef);
    ABRecordRef contactPerson = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, record);
/*---Here you get your updated Record Refence----*/
//Do your other stuff here
}
```

Comment: I have classes available: ABAddressBookRef, ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions . may need to import the library?

Comment: Add  <Foundation/Foundation.h>, <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h> this two frameworks if not added.

Comment: using Foundation;
using AddressBook;
using AddressBookUI;

Comment: this liblary not have those methods

Comment: I need to detect of changes in the native address book

Comment: Actully it works fine in xcode. Sorry, i dont know about xamarin.